# Alternatives to repeatedly passing a dbcontext from a controller to a model?

Tags: c#, dbcontext

Is there a way to avoid passing a DbContext from the Controller to a Model every time I want to access it? Right now I pass the DbContext in the Model constructor, but this seems inefficient. Is there a way to make the DbContext available to the Models directly?

My current approach:

```
Controller{    
  var context;//set when the controller is initialized

  public ActionResult MyMethod(){
    var res=new MyClass(context);
  }
}
```

Comment: What context are we talking about here? Is it the DbContext?

Comment: @Xhulio yep, I will edit the post to make that clearer

Comment: I don't have enough information to answer this properly. But passing the context to the model is generally not a good idea. You are not following the separation of concerns. The model should just hold data and not retrieve it. I would suggest creating a repository that will retrieve your models and in this repository, you can use dependency injection to inject your context. But it depends a lot on the rest of your architecture for me to say anything more.